# Get property names from class method

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Is there a way to get the names of the properties inside the GetPKs method? maybe using reflection?

so in the example below I need to somehow get an object[] that returns "Id", "Id2". Id3 will be ignored. I don't need the values but the Id names

```
public class MyClass
{ 
     public int Id; 
     public int Id2;
     public int Id3;
     public object[] GetPKs() => new object[] { Id, Id2 };
 }
```

Comment: could you please post more context code. Where is `Id` and `Id2` declared?

Comment: You would have to decompile the code. Not trivial, why do you need to know the names of the *things* that provided the values for that array?

Comment: yes I need the name of the variables: Id and Id2 in this case

Comment: That sounds a little bit like an X/Y problem. How and why do those values end up in this array, and why do you need the names? What is your aim to achieve

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that your `Id`,`Id2` and `Id3` are just integer values, so if `Id2==Id3` you don't know what you have to print out, `Id2` or `Id3`
If we **assume**, that all your properties are different, you could go this way:

```
public class MyClass
{ 
     public int Id; 
     public int Id2;
     public int Id3;
     public object[] GetPKs() => new object[] { Id, Id2 };
     public IEnumerable<string> GetPNames() 
     {
        var allProperties = GetType().GetProperties().Select(x=>new {x.Name, Value = x.GetValue(this)});
        var allFields = GetType().GetFields().Select(x=>new {x.Name, Value = x.GetValue(this)});
        var dict = allProperties.Concat(allFields).ToDictionary(x=>x.Value, x=>x.Name);
        foreach(var value in GetPKs())
        {
            yield return dict[value];
        }
     }
}
```

That codes iterates over fields and over properties. If you have only fields, you could simplify it:

```
public class MyClass
{ 
     public int Id; 
     public int Id2;
     public int Id3;
     public object[] GetPKs() => new object[] { Id, Id2 };
     public IEnumerable<string> GetPNames() 
     {          
        var allFields = GetType().GetFields()
                                 .Select(x=>new {x.Name, Value = x.GetValue(this)});
        var dict = allFields.ToDictionary(x=>x.Value, x=>x.Name);
        foreach(var value in GetPKs())
        {
            yield return dict[value];
        }
     }
}
```

Perhaps better way would be to store not objects, but expressions, pointing to your fields. In that case, you could extract field names from expression, doesn't matter what values they have.

```
public class MyClass
{ 
     public int Id; 
     public int Id2;
     public int Id3;
     public Expression<Func<MyClass,object>>[] GetPKs() 
                       => new Expression<Func<MyClass,object>>[] { x=>Id, x=>Id2 };
     public IEnumerable<string> GetPNames()
     {
        return GetPKs().Select(expr =>
              ((MemberExpression)((UnaryExpression)expr.Body).Operand).Member.Name);
     }
}
```